# How do I add a payment view block to Commerce Order page?

Tags: forms, commerce

At example.com/user/123/orders/993 the customer sees an Order #993 page to review the history of a particular order.

I already have a View with a block display of the payment information for a given order.

How can I attach this block to that particular form/page (which is generated in code) such that I can pass the UserID and OrderID to the view?

EDIT: What I want to do is 'inject' the Payment view/block I've created -inside- the form generated in commerce_cart.module (after the line items entity reference) so that I can theme it in a decent looking way.

Answer (score 0):

For the block, you can set the visibility to `user/*/orders/*`

For the info in the block, you can use a contextual filter that checks the user and displays the needed info.

Comment: Thanks. Technically that 'works' but it looks awful. I'm editing the question because what I really want is to be able to add the payment block (or view) INSIDE the 'form' that is generated by commerce_cart.module.